# Android bidirectional view with recycling views?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view, recycle

After several hours of investigation, I didn't find any view in Android who can scroll in both directions with ability of recycling views.

What I'm looking for? I need a view that can display grid of 256x256 buttons at all.

On the screen can be displayed for one moment ~ 12x8 buttons, others need located one the bottom and right outside of the screen.

The most similar effect I found here,

http://wiresareobsolete.com/2015/02/recyclerview-layoutmanager-redux/comment-page-1/

but provided code on GitHub repository is broken - when I try make a fast scrolling - the window came white.

Answer (score -1):

I have not worked it out but I Hope this might work

```
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

     </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</HorizontalScrollView>
```